# Python keeps crashing and there is a segmentation error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, panoramas

I am trying to create a panorama from a bunch of images and so had downloaded a repo from github. Now when i run the program, I am not sure why but python crashes and I get a segmentation error on my terminal. I am currently runnning it on pycharm. All my images are loaded and then it crashes and and then displays the error. I want to create a panorama from a video file or from a bunch of frames of a long scene. In this program. I just want to read the files in that folder and then start stitching them one by one to get the final image.

This is the error

INFO:root:reading image from /Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Raw Data/Office data/frame030.png
INFO:root:reading image from /Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Raw Data/Office data/frame024.png

zsh: segmentation fault python3 image_stitching.py --display

[I have attached a snapshot of my screen as well for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7BmM.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'Will Brennan'

# Built-in Modules
import os
import argparse
import logging

import cv2

import helpers
from combine import combine_images
from helpers import *
from matching import compute_matches

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    #parser.add_argument('image_paths', type=str, nargs='+', help="paths to one or more images or image directories")
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--debug', dest='debug', action='store_true', help='enable debug logging')
    parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', dest='quiet', action='store_true', help='disable all logging')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--display', dest='display', action='store_true', help="display result")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--save', dest='save', action='store_true', help="save result to file")
    parser.add_argument("--save_path", dest='save_path', default="stitched.png", type=str, help="path to save result")
    parser.add_argument('-k', '--knn', dest='knn', default=2, type=int, help="Knn cluster value")
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--lowe', dest='lowe', default=0.7, type=float, help='acceptable distance between points')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--min', dest='min_correspondence', default=10, type=int, help='min correspondences')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.debug:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")

    logging.info("beginning sequential matching")
    print(cv2.__version__)

    #if helpers.is_cv2():
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
    #elif helpers.is_cv3():
        #sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    #else:
        #raise RuntimeError("error! unknown version of python!")

    result = None
    result_gry = None

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher({'algorithm': 0, 'trees': 5}, {'checks': 50})

    image_paths = ["/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Raw Data/Office data/"]
    image_index = -1
    for image_path in image_paths:
        #print(image_path)
        if not os.path.exists(image_path):
            logging.error('{0} is not a valid path'.format(image_path))
            continue
        if os.path.isdir(image_path):
            extensions = [".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"]
            for file_path in os.listdir(image_path):
                if os.path.splitext(file_path)[1].lower() in extensions:
                    print(file_path)
                    image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_path, file_path))
            continue

        logging.info("reading image from {0}".format(image_path))
        image_colour = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_colour, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

        image_index += 1

        if image_index == 0:
            result = image_colour
            result_gry = image_gray
            continue

        logger.debug('computing sift features')
        features0 = sift.detectAndCompute(result_gry, None)
        features1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_gray, None)

        matches_src, matches_dst, n_matches = image_stitching.compute_matches(features0, features1, flann, knn=args.knn)

        if n_matches < args.min_correspondence:
            logger.error("error! too few correspondences")
            continue

        logger.debug("computing homography between accumulated and new images")
        H, mask = cv2.findHomography(matches_src, matches_dst, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        result = combine_images(image_colour, result, H)

        if args.display and not args.quiet:
            helpers.display('result', result)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        result_gry = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    logger.info("processing complete!")

    if args.display and not args.quiet:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    if args.save:
        logger.info("saving stitched image to {0}".format(args.save_path))
        helpers.save_image(args.save_path, result)
```

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/python-crashes-and-shows-segmentation-error/930

Answer (score 0):

The Same Happened To Me I Tried It From Visual Studio Code and It Worked Perfectly Fine. I Hope That's The Same Case For You.